# ".d.ts" Files, how to declare Promise result as result of a Function

Tags: javascript, typescript, .d.ts

I've written a small async function to help me returning Promises result as an Array of two element.

My function is

```js
/* will.js */
const will = async (result) => {
  try {
    const result = await funcResult;
    return [null, result];
  }
  catch (err) {
    return [err, null];
  }
}

export default will;

/* any-file.js */
import will from './will';

function someFunction() {
  const [err, data] = await will(someFetch());
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  // ecc. ecc.
}
```

I'm trying to write relative `.d.ts` file. The function passed to `will` always return a Promise that resolve in different times: sometimes will resolve in `string`, sometimes in `boolean`... in that case it's not a big problem, but if i'll pass a `mongoose` query execution (for example) i would like that `will` function will return a Promise that resolved in `MongooseDocument` to have Code Completion correctly.

eg

```js
const [findUserError, user] = await will(User.findOne({ email }).exec());

// From this point i would like
// user variable is `MongooseDocument` type
// as the return value of User.findOne({ email }).exec()
// is `Promise<MongooseDocument>`
```

I'm relative new to `.d.ts` file, i've tried to simply write

```js
declare function will(result: Promise<T>): Promise<[any, T]>

export default will
```

but obviously it doesn't work...

Could someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: `T` needs to be declared `will<T extends object>` so it looks like this `declare function will<T extends object>(result: Promise<T>): Promise<[any, T]>`

Comment: You're the Best. This `declare function will<T extends any>(result: Promise<T>): Promise<[any, T]>` solved all my problems. Why you "Comment" and not "Answer" my question? I can't assign you the Green Mark

Comment: I don't think you need `extends any` if you don't plan to extend anything specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) the Generic key needs to be defined, and when doing that with a function, it can be defined after the function name. In this case `will<T>`.

```js
declare function will<T>(result: Promise<T>): Promise<[any, T]>
```

The same goes for a class such as `MyClass<T>`

```js
declare class MyClass<T> {
  myMethod<A>(param: T): Promise<A>
}
```

When a generic is an object and it is possible to be of multiple types you can use extends that extends a base object.

```js
declare class Base {}
declare class A extends Base {}
declare class B extends Base {}

declare class Handler<T extends Base> {
  addItem(item: T): void
}
```